# How to remove comma from taxonomy tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to style my taxonomy tags value. Actually In this Tags accepts comma separated value, so if I am rendering it on page it comes along with the comma.

[image]

I want separate values without comma.

How can I do that?

Comment: Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are using views to display the nodes. If so, then click on the tags field in the Fields and in the "MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS" give space in the separator.